# Cancelling an alarm that starts within a class that launches when the reboot is complete

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-context, reboot

Here is my class which launches and sets an alarm when the phone is rebooted.

```
public class NotifStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{

private static AlarmNotif reAlarm = new AlarmNotif();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{


    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
    {
        reAlarm.SetAlarm(context.getApplicationContext());

    }
}

}
```

and here's my alarm's receiver class:

```
public class AlarmNotifReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

PendingIntent pi;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
//stuff
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifReceiver.class);
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*1000, pi); // Millisec * Second
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi);
}


}
```

Now, if I use `SetAlarm()` as the phone is open I am able to use `CancelAlarm()` and actually cancel it. But whenever I reboot the phone and set the alarm by using the above class `NotifStart` I am unable to cancel it. I tried to use the cancel method from within the `NotifStart` but since I can't really give the context of a non-activity class as `onReceive` it just doesn't work.

Comment: can you please clarify what's wrong? the problem is unclear

Comment: how come it is unclear? I can't cancel my alarm which is set on reboot? Why is it unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CancelAlarm(Context context) your pi might be null, check and re-create it with the same requestCode before performing cancel.

```
    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifReceiver.class);
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.cancel(pi);
}
```

Comment: tried what you said and turns out pi was really returning null and turns it this works pretty well, thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

**A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.**

So when you call your `CancelAlarm` your pending intent might be `null` or not equal to pending intent used for setting alarm.

Comment: Do not use `BroadcastReceiver` for wrapping up your alarm functionality. Just create a simple class with needed functions. Or set up PI again in Cancel method